# Regular Expression for Extension of File

Tags: javascript, regex

I need 1 regular expression to put restrictions on the file types using it's extension.

I tried this for restricting the file type of html, .class, etc.

1. `/(\.|\/)[^(html|class|js|css)]$/i`
2. `/(\.|\/)[^html|^class|^js|^css]$/i`

I need to restrict a total of 10-15 types of files. In my application there is a field for accepted file type, and according to the requirement I have file types which is to be restricted. So I need a regular expression using negation of restricted file type only.

The plugin code is like:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|txt)$/i
});
```

I can specify the acceptedFileType but i have given the requirement to restrict a set of file.

Comment: Javascript? Or which language?

Comment: It will probably be easier to have a loop and compare the extension of the file with each of the extensions in your list. If any extension matches, then you break the loop and prevent the file from going further.

Comment: Make a regex for matching the restricted file types. If it matches DON"T do it.

Comment: Actually,I m using this in one of the Jquery plugin code.and it has to pass 1 parameter like AcceptedFileType. thts i need the reg exp. otherwise loop method is best.

Comment: @LeeMeador : that plugin code accepts only AcceptedFileType.I searched for the restrictedFileType parameter,but it doesnt accept.

Comment: Why do you think you need a regular expression? Just find the last `.` in the string, and `.slice()` off that substring. Then check if it's in an array of accepted extensions or not

Comment: What happens if the user uploads a file with a valid extension, but it contians html/js/css/etc?

Comment: @Ian : I m using jquery plugin for file upload.for that i have to pass the parameter "AcceptedFileType" to the fileUpload function.thtsy i need this reg expression

Comment: @Gray : Currently it is getting uploaded.I have to restrict that uploding.

Comment: @iRunner You don't **need** a regular expression. Look: http://jsfiddle.net/rP5Lq/1/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try `/^(.*\.(?!(htm|html|class|js)$))?[^.]*$/i`

Try it here: http://regexr.com?35rp0

It will also work with extensionless files.

As all the regexes, it's complex to explain... Let's start from the end

```
[^.]*$ 0 or more non . characters
( ... )? if there is something before (the last ?)

.*\.(?!(htm|html|class|js)$) Then it must be any character in any number .*
                             followed by a dot \.
                             not followed by htm, html, class, js (?! ... )
                             plus the end of the string $
                             (this so that htmX doesn't trigger the condition)

^ the beginning of the string
```

This one `(?!(htm|html|class|js)` is called zero width negative lookahead. It's explained at least 10 times every day on SO, so you can look anywhere :-)

Comment: It matches the empty string. Don't know if that's bad or not.

Comment: Explain the negated lookahead. It would be a better answer that way.

Comment: @Gray Yes now it does :-)

Comment: @LeeMeador Now it does match empty string.

Comment: @xanatos Ha, well done.. but now, you can use two dots! ex: `test..html` +1 though - good effort so far.

Comment: @Gray Two dots should be matched because it ends with ".html" and that meets the criterion.

Comment: @LeeMeador I believed that issue was fixed by xanatos, because it no longer matches the 'two dots' file.

Comment: The change was only in the explanation. Will it match "bob.properties.html" now? I think it should. It just shouldn't match "bob.html.txt"

Comment: @LeeMeador There is a regexr example with the latest version... You can test there

Comment: You might want to make the example and the top line of your answer and the explanation parts match each other. They don't quite match now.

Comment: @LeeMeador While the explanation is probably confusing because it's done partially backwards and partially forward, it's complete. Every single character of the regex is explained.

Comment: I dont know why but using this reg expression also the files like .class and .html are getting uploded. I m stuck now

Comment: This regex fails on a filename with multiple extensions like malicious.decoyExtenion.js

Negative lookbehind from the end of line is safer way to do it, like .+(?<!vtt|jpg|webp)$

Comment: @RyanMcGrath Not in the regxr it would seem: https://regexr.com/5ocnu .

Answer (score 2):

You seem to misunderstand how a character class works. A character class matches only a single character. The character chosen is the one from all of them in there. So, your character class:

```
[^(html|class|js|css)]
```

doesn't match `html` or `class` in sequence. It just matches a single character out of all the distinct character in that class.

That said, for your particular task, you need to use *negative look-ahead*:

```
/(?!.*[.](?:html|class|js|css)$).*/
```

---

However, I would also consider using the String library in my respective language, instead of using regex, to achieve this task. You just need to test, whether the string ends with any of those extension.

Comment: In U.S. and U.K. English, "that said" means "however". Does it mean something different in Indian English?

Comment: @ruakh In my part of the US, it means "in addition" or "another way of looking at it"

Comment: @ruakh. Here it means - "in addition to that".

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using JQuery, you might consider skipping the regex all together and going with an array of valid extensions instead:

```
// store the file extensions (easy to maintain, if changesa are needed)
var aValidExtensions = ["htm", "html", "class", "js"];
// split the filename on "."
var aFileNameParts = file_name.split(".");

// if there are at least two pieces to the file name, continue the check
if (aFileNameParts.length > 1) {
    // get the extension (i.e., the last "piece" of the file name)
    var sExtension = aFileNameParts[aFileNameParts.length-1];

    // if the extension is in the array, return true, if not, return false
    return ($.inArray(sExtension, aValidExtensions) >= 0) ? true : false; 
}
else {
    return false;  // invalid file name format (no file extension)
}
```

The big advantage here is in the ease of maintenance . . . changing acceptable file extensions is a quick update to the array (or even a property or CMS update, depending on how fancy things are   :)   ).  Also, `regex` has a habit of being a little process intensive, so this should be more efficient (though, I haven't tested this particular case yet).

Comment: this code does not use regex, but works fine. thanks. just better to use var aFileNameParts = file_name.toLowerCase().split(".") instead of line 4